# How can I escape a single quote correctly in when using/parsing a remote variable?

Tags: bash, parsing, escaping, single-quotes

I am trying to escape the following variable which is located on a remote server:

```
ssh root@$HWNODEIP "echo '    set root='$getgrub''   >> /etc/grub.d/40_custom"
```

In short I need to add a **single quote before and after** the variable **$getgrub**.

I tried several things like putting them in double quotes (") and escaping () it, however no luck. The only result I am getting is similar things like: "sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unknown option to `s'"

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to make this work?
I also tried storing the $getgrub variable with single quotes included, however they don't appear in the file /etc/grub.d/40_custom?!

Probably I am making somewhere a mistake, but I cannot seem to find it.

Thanks.

//edit

If I run the following command from the server:

```
ssh root@$HWNODEIP  "echo '    set root='$getgrub'' >> /etc/grub.d/40_custom"
```

And I check the file the variable is in the file, however not with the single quotes in front and behind?

Output (cat) of the file:

> set root=EXAMPLE

Where it should read:

> set root='EXAMPLE'

Strange...

Comment: Try:
```ssh root@$HWNODEIP "echo \"set root='$getgrub'\""
```

Comment: Nevermind. I adapted your code and it works. Will report back in a minute.

This worked for me: ssh root@$HWNODEIP "echo \"set root='$getgrub'\" >> /etc/grub.d/40_custom"

Please create that as an answer. So I can vote for your answer. TY!

Comment: Nice! Added an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes for echo:

**Example**

```sh
$ ssh user@server "echo \"set example='test'\" >> example.txt"
```

**Result (example.txt at the server)**

```sh
$ cat example.txt
set example='test'
```